# iOS Make ImageView Align to Top Corner

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to set a background that fits in both portrait and landscape. Problem I have is there is a logo in the top right of the image.  The size of the image is 2048 x 2048.

In portrait mode it's fine but when in landscape I lose the logo as it clips to all sides.

I'm using auto layout in Interface Builder and have set all constraints to 0 and view to aspect fill.

Is it possible for the image view to pin the top right corner to the top right of the screen and for it to clip only on the left and the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about setting your background ContentMode to Top Right, and adjust Layouting Constrains to view bounds ? this image will not get resized and logo will always appear.

instead u can get logo separately and place your image without logo, and just set logo to snap to right and top borders

Comment: Your a star works perfect. Would love to have the image of the logo as a separate item but the whole idea is for people to select there own background and logo from the gallery until Apple fix the incredibly annoying fact that you can't use a transparent png in the galley I am forced to have the logo on the background

Comment: i didn't face such issue before that u can't use a transparent png in the galley ? i didn't get well what you referring to

Comment: if you copy a png file to photo gallery and it has a transparent background it turns the background white There appears to be no workaround unless anyone can tell me different you can get apps that will do it but thats only for copy and paste. If you put the transparent png in your bundle it works fine but I want my users to be able to use their own designs

Comment: [check this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860379/how-to-save-a-uiimage-as-a-transperent-png)

Comment: Thanks for this Mortgy its interesting if I was creating the logo in the app But I want people to make there own using any paint program and store it in the photo gallery the app then allows you to pick it from the photo gallery and display it in an image view